# cannot call json_object_keys on an array

Tags: postgresql

How to insert sub_mark keys and values to tempory table

```
    
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_marks AS
    SELECT json_object_keys(mark_coll->'sub_mark'),mark_coll -> 'sub_mark'
    FROM json_array_elements(mark_coll) ;
```

This is the function parameter

```
select * from add_marks('b0c98996-1250-45ef-89f3-9ccaf1d84ed4','{"sub_mark":[{"PAT45":60}]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if the column your_column of the table your_table is with data type json AND all the stored values in that column are of json type 'array' :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_marks AS
SELECT json_object_keys(mark_coll->'sub_mark'),mark_coll -> 'sub_mark'
FROM your_table AS t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(t.your_column) AS mark_coll ;
```

If you can use the jsonb data type instead of json, which is recommended in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html), you can try this which does not depend on the jsonb structure :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_marks AS
SELECT c->'key', c->'value'
FROM your_table AS t
cross join lateral jsonb_path_query(t.your_column, '$.** ? (@.type() == "object").keyvalue()') as c
```

Comment: Is there any way if I don't store value in the table. I am passing the array through the parameter in the function.